# Why is following regular expression as greedy?

Tags: javascript, regex

Why does `(.*?)` group in `/({\/\* )?#if (.*?)( \*\/})?/` not capture `process.env.MODE === "std"` when using `{/* #if process.env.MODE === "std" */}` as input?

I am aware removing `?` from last group works… that said, it is a requirement.

Is it possible to work around this?

Comment: Because the last group is optional.

Comment: Thanks for helping out @JvdV. Is there a way to write this so that last group is optional (which is a requirement)?

Comment: What about end of string anchor? `/({\/\* )?#if (.*?)( \*\/})?$/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Using `$` is promising! Thanks! Are you aware of any other workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to have an optional pattern at the end after an optional pattern (like `.*?`), you can convert the `.*?` lazy dot pattern into a [*tempered greedy token*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970):

```
({\/\* )?#if ((?:(?! \*\/}).)*)( \*\/})?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DBSsGw/1).

The `.*?` is changed into a pattern that matches any char, zero or more but as many as possible occurrences, that is not a starting point of the  `*/}` char sequence.

*Details*:

- `({\/\* )?` - an optional Group 1: `/*` and space
- `#if`  - an `#if`  string
- `((?:(?! \*\/}).)*)` - Group 2: any char other than line break chars, zero or more but as many as possible occurrences, that is not a starting point of the  `*/}` char sequence
- `( \*\/})?` - an optional Group 3:  `*/}` string

Answer (score -1):

remove the optional '?' from the end of the regex which is making the last group optional

it should be

```js
({\/\* )?#if (.*?)( \*\/})
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out… problem is that last group is optional.